# Having trouble with "Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed" solutions

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.04, initramfs

I just build my first PC, turned it on for the first time, and attempting to install Linux Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from a bootable USB.

As many others have had the "decoding failed" problem I cannot seem to figure out how to use any of the solutions posted to fix the issue regarding my situation.

Any or some advice would be greatly appreciated as I have no idea what I am doing nor have any technical knowledge.

--

Thank You

[Image of error when attempting to boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyDTH.jpg)

[Ubuntu prompt (I clicked enter on the first line ubuntu)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByaTi.jpg)

Comment: Is this error occurring when booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and trying to install Ubuntu, or after you've installed Ubuntu, and are booting it from your HDD/SSD?

Comment: I believe the first one. I turned on the PC for the first time. Then plugged the USB that I have Ubuntu downloaded on. I rebooted the PC, and was prompted with the image for which I added to the above question under "Ubuntu prompt"

Comment: When you boot to the Ubuntu Live USB, it does a file check... did that pass for you, or were there errors? Once you see the GRUB menu, select **Ubuntu**.

Comment: After I clicked on Ubuntu from the GRUB menu I was greeted with the image that I posted above, which said the decoding failed.

Comment: When you downloaded the .iso file, did you checksum it before burning it to flash? How/where did you burn it to flash?

Comment: Your advice has led me to redo the entire process. I am using a different software to write Ubuntu onto my flash. I used Rufus the first time and now Universal USB Installer. I do not understand what you mean by checking the .ios file before burning it to the flash.

Comment: At the same place where you downloaded the .iso file, there should also be 3-4 files with filenames similar to md5sums or sha5sums. Those are text files that contain the checksums for the .iso file. If you download/read the file, you'll see. For example, then in `terminal`, you do `md5sum filename.iso` and compare it to what you see in the md5sums file to see if they match. If they don't, you've got a bad download.

Comment: I opened the md5sums text files and attempted to enter the 'md5sum filename.iso' command and received this message. "Not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I redownloaded the ubuntu .iso file and tried it with the new installer and I get the same decoding failed message.

Comment: The `md5sum filename.iso` is two words, and "filename" gets replaced by the actual downloaded file name. Since you can't boot the Ubuntu Live USB, manually enter your BIOS and see if you can find the version number. Tell me that, and exactly what make/model # your computer or motherboard is. Do you also have Windows installed?

Comment: Should I just get a different distro of Linux? I really do not care what I have, I just do not want Windows on my new PC. Mint Cinnamon, Zorin, Elementary?

Comment: Maybe. But most of them are based on Debian... the same thing that Ubuntu is based on. Let's do the BIOS check, and make sure we're not fighting ourselves.

Comment: I went with Manjaro. It worked. I truly appreciate your help and I want to say that your efforts have not been wasted. I would have given up and bought Windows if it were not for you. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it's worked out for you. Just for fun, see if Manjaro can do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the make/model # of your computer of motherboard.

Comment: That does not sound fun at all, and why do you keep asking me? -_-

Comment: What's not fun? It's a simple command to tell us the version number of your BIOS. I needed the make/model # of your computer or motherboard, so I can go to the manufacturer's web site to check for a newer BIOS for you. I don't ask for anything that I asked for before. Remember... you came here for help... and I was just trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660

The workaround that I applied to solve the issue was:

changing setting in initramfs.conf editting the file with sudo rights

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
```

then change the line with `COMPRESS=lz4` to `COMPRESS=gzip`

boot time with lz4 was:

```
Startup finished in 10.074s (firmware) + 6.687s (loader) + 6.451s (kernel) + 30.951s (userspace) = 54.164s 
graphical.target reached after 29.969s in userspace
```

now with gzip:

```
Startup finished in 10.046s (firmware) + 8.307s (loader) + 7.636s (kernel) + 27.035s (userspace) = 53.026s 
graphical.target reached after 26.279s in userspace
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had that problem just now along with coloured lines on the black screen (heard a lot of people had a similar issue). Not an expert on the topic but I'll share what happened on my end that resolved the issue.

Changing /`etc/initramfs-tools/initramf.conf`

`COMPRESS=lz4` to `COMPRESS=gzip` did the trick of the error message.

There was still a problem in that it still booted to a black screen with coloured lines (I'm hearing a lot of people with this issue also have that). What I found was that by updating the video card driver to the Nvidia one (assuming you're using an Nvidia GPU) as well as doing all the software updates then restarting seemed to not only work (in removing the lines), but I also got a notification on boot-up from that point on that the blocks were cleaned (probably from the first step).